# Laravel ordenar itens de uma tabela a partir dos valores de outra

Tags: php, laravel

Possuo duas tabelas, uma chamada propostas e outra propostas_itens

```
propostas
-id
-nome
-descricao

propostas_itens
-id
-proposta_id
-quantidade
-valor
```

Uma proposta possui muitos itens, preciso listar as propostas de acordo com seu valor total, sendo assim tenho de efetuar a soma do valor de todos os itens relacionados a uma proposta e fazer um orderBy por esse valor, mas não estou conseguindo efetuar isso no Laravel utilizo a versão 5.7

Tentei efetuar um join() e depois um groupBy() mas não consigo agrupar os resultados para depois operar eles no orderBy()

```
$propostas->join('propostas_itens', 'propostas_itens.proposta_id', '=', 'propostas.id')->groupBy('propostas_itens.proposta_id');
```

Fico grato pela ajuda de todos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer no *inverso da relação* e buscar primeiro agrupar os `propostas_itens`  e com o comando `with` chamar a relação da `proposta`, exemplo:

```
App\PropostaItens::groupBy('proposta_id')
      ->selectRaw('proposta_id,sum(valor)')
      ->orderBy('sum(valor)')
      ->with('proposta')
      ->get()
```

o resultado é o seguinte:

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2850
 all: [
   App\PropostaItens {#2858
     proposta_id: 2,
     sum(valor): "50.00",
     proposta: App\Proposta {#2869
       id: 2,
       nome: "P2",
       descricao: "P2",
     },
   },
   App\PropostaItens {#2855
     proposta_id: 3,
     sum(valor): "190.25",
     proposta: App\Proposta {#2870
       id: 3,
       nome: "P3",
       descricao: "P3",
     },
   },
   App\PropostaItens {#2840
     proposta_id: 1,
     sum(valor): "200.00",
     proposta: App\Proposta {#2864
       id: 1,
       nome: "P1",
       descricao: "P1",
     },
   },
 ],
}
```

na hora de utilizar faça assim:

```
foreach($result as $r)
{
    echo $r->proposta->id;
    echo $r->proposta->nome;
    echo $r->proposta->descricao;
}
```